# How to fix incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

When I execute this code, I'm getting an error in the SQL command

> Incorrect syntax near '?'

This is my code:

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT [username], [password] FROM [stud_table] WHERE [username] = ?", connection)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", Me.UsernameTextBox.Text)

Try
    connection.Open()

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    Dim rec As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteScalar()

    If rec.HasRows Then
        rec.Read()

        If Me.PasswordTextBox.Text.ToLower = rec.Item("password").ToString Then
            MsgBox("Login successful")
            Me.Hide()
            user_profile.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Login unsuccessful, Incorrect Password", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Login unsuccessful, Invalid UserName", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
    End If
    rec.Close()
Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
    MsgBox("Login unsuccessful,no connection", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Sql Server doesn't use the ? as placeholder for parameters. It uses the @ followed by a string representing the parameter name

Comment: Do not store passwords as plain text.

Comment: You are using an SqlCommand and an SqlDataAdapter but you are catching an OleDbException. What database are you using???

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter names in the query:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT [username],[password] FROM [stud_table] WHERE [username] = @username", connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar) = Me.UsernameTextBox.Text
```

Comment: Please do not suggest the use of AddWithValue. There are many articles explaining that there are problems with it, e.g. [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html) But the syntax correction is otherwise good.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the note, I've edited the syntax correction with the preferred overload.

Comment: Thank you so much , it helped to solve the syntax error.

Comment: @aartitirthapramodkumar If that has solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.